# What's the difference between using the verb "change" transitively and intransitively?

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs, transitivity

I am confused about using transitive and intransitive verbs for making passive sentences. Especially when that verb can be both (like the verb *change*).

Comment: Could you cast that as a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Change* is one of a number of [***ergative***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb) verbs in English. These are used in both transitive and intransitive senses:

- In the transitive sense, the *Agent* is the *subject* of the verb and acts upon a *Patient*, the *direct object*.

  > John (*Agent*, *subject*) **broke** the window (*Patient*, *direct object*).
  >   Mary (*Agent*, *subject*) **walked** the dog (*Patient*, *direct object*).
  >   This book (*Agent*, *subject*) **changed** my life (*Patient*, *direct object*)
- In the intransitive sense, the Agent is deleted and the *Patient* becomes the subject of the verb, which thus represents the action as “performed” by the Patient.

  > The window (*Patient*, *subject*) **broke**.
  >   The dog (*Patient*, *subject*) **walked**.
  >   My life (*Patient*, *subject*) **changed**.

As you know, only *transitive* verbs can be cast into the *passive*, but the effect is very similar — the *Patient* becomes the *subject*. In a *passive* construction, however, the *Agent* may be restored as the object of a prepositional phrase with *by*:

> The window (*Patient*, *subject*) **was broken** by John (*Agent*).
>   The dog (*Patient*, *subject*) **was walked** by Mary (*Agent*).
>   My life (*Patient*, *subject*) **was changed** by this book (*Agent*).

Ergative verbs mostly designate a change of state, and there is often very little difference, if any, in *meaning* between the transitive and intransitive versions.  The same outcome is described, and the difference is largely one of focus — the transitive sense puts the emphasis on the Agent, the intransitive sense puts the emphasis on the outcome and ignores the Agent altogether.

> Tom boiled water.       The water boiled.
>   This book changed my life.    My life changed.

However, there is substantially more difference when the Patient is animate and the verb designates a change which the Patient is capable of effecting by its own effort:

> Mary walked the dog through the park.   The dog walked through the park.
>   Lee moved Stuart to the left wing.      Stuart moved to the left wing.

Answer (score 2):

Verbs can form passives only when they are used transitively. The active sentence *The government changed the law* is transitive, and so allows the passive construction *The law has been changed by the government.* On the other hand, *You have changed a lot over the past ten years* is intransitive when it means that the person addressed has a different appearance, and so does not allow a passive form.

Comment: For Example: _When I got Married, my life was changed_ or _When I got Married, my life changed_ ??? this is my question.

Comment: I think im my example the second one is true, am I right?

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Something got lost in transferring my answer from MS Word. Now corrected.

Comment: @yaa110. _When I got married, my life was changed_ and _When I got married, my life changed_ are both possible English sentences. In the first, _changed_ is the past participle of _change_ and is used with _was_ to make a passive construction. In the second, _changed_ is the past tense of _change_ and is used intransitively.

Comment: do my examples have the same meaning?

Comment: @yaa110. They do, but the event is seen from different aspects. The first suggests that something unspecified, probably the marriage itself, caused the change. The second assigns no explicit responsibility for the change. The form used would depend on the context, and on the impression the write wanted to convey.