# "Has been changed" or "has changed"?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, active-voice

Debate with a fellow writer: should I say "My email ID has been changed" or "My email ID has changed"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. A closely related question is [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95912/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-verb-change-transitively-and-intransit/95924#95924).

Answer (score 14):

Both are possible, grammatical, and idiomatic, but "my email ID has changed" simply means that the ID is no longer the same, while "my email ID has been changed" puts more stress on the fact that *someone* is responsible for actively changing the ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed it, "I have changed my email" or "My email has changed". If someone else changed it for you, "My email has been changed".

Answer (score -4):

My email Id has changed--- The Id is changed and it is still going on ( the process of changing mail Id )

My mail Id was changed ---- The Id is changed in the past

Comment: No, to express that the process is ongoing, you would say *the ID is changing* or *the ID is being changed*.